# Accessing the memory locations created on heap

Tags: c++, pointers

Why the following C++ code does not give a segmentation fault, I am trying to access something that I have deleted.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun ( int * ptr )
{
    delete ptr;
}
int main ()
{
    int * ptr = new int ;
    *ptr = 6;
    fun ( ptr );
    cout<<*ptr;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: what result are you getting?

Comment: It is one of my assignment questions that I got on Segmentation fault

Comment: try that code first rather posting for solution.

Comment: I tried it doesn't give segmentation fault

Comment: Please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing something you've deleted doesn't automatically result in segfault.

The behavior is undefined. It ***might*** segfault, it might ***not***. You can never know.

Comment: How can you guarantee that it will not cause segfault ?

Comment: @utility Because the C++ standard defines it to be *undefined behavior*. It doesn't say it should cause a segfault. Segfault only happens if the OS is not happy with you trying to access the memory address.